# Check for internet connection in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, connectivity

How do I check for an active internet connection in Flash using Actionscript 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using AIR, you can use the [`ServiceMonitor`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/air/net/ServiceMonitor.html) class.

Otherwise you might want to consider rolling your own with a `URLLoader` coupled with a timer with an exponential backoff.

Answer (score 1):

to expand on martineno's answer about rolling your own using the URLLoader, read about the [HTTPStatusEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/HTTPStatusEvent.html) in the documentation.

at the end of the document Adobe includes an example for checking for the existence of a file on a server, but the same could be applied to simply check for an internet connection.