# Event to detect internet connectivity in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, flex4, air

Is there any event to detect internet conectivity in flex or actionscript3.I tried URLMonitor and networkInfo classes,is there any other event to detect because in URLMonitor class I need to add an url to it which is not possible in my case and in networkInfo class,it does not get called every time.

My requirement is when the application and suddenly if the connection goes off I need to raise an error.Any ideas??

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: See [actionscript 3 - Check for internet connection in Flash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272080/check-for-internet-connection-in-flash)

Comment: @antinome,can u give a example on how to use service monitor class?

Comment: why you cannot add a url ? you can check for google.com each time... this means you have internet connection. If you want to check your server add the server url. I say you use urlMonitor with google.

Comment: @TiMeister,I have several http services in my app,so if i add one url to urlMonitor only that url is loading and rest of my url's are not working.Its giving fault event.Any solutions???

Comment: @Naveen: there is an example **[here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8f6c0-7ffe.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7cbf)** under _HTTP Monitoring_ using URLMonitor (a subclass of ServiceMonitor). But I think this is for AIR apps only so if you are making something for the Flash Player you would need to use the URLLoader approach.

Comment: @antinome,Thanks i got it working you can add this as answer!!thanks once again

Comment: ok... so first of all you are not checking for INTERNET connection as you describe. you want to see if any of your services is not reacheable which is different.

Answer (score 0):

What I do in my applications is (I'm using amfPhp) have a onFault handler. So when x amount of time nothing comes from the server show the user a popup message. Yes, it's not as fast as you would want it , but it works.